# How to globally mock an Angular service for Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine

I've configured the browser's console object as an Angular service, so that I can inject it into other services, like this:

```
export const CONSOLE = new InjectionToken<Console>('Console', {
  providedIn: 'root',
  factory: () => console
});
```

In Jasmine tests though, I want to inject a mock version of this service, so that my Jasmine test code doesn't start attaching spies to the actual `console` object (as I'm unsure whether they'll be automatically *detached* at the end of a test, since the service - i.e. the underlying `console` object - is never destroyed).

I can do this at the beginning of a describe block, viz:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  const console = {
    error: () => {
    }
  };

  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      {provide: CONSOLE, useValue: console}
    ]
  });
});
```

However, I don't want to have to do this in every test file.

**Is there some way I can define a global `beforeEach()` in a standard Angular CLI project, that will run before all of my Jasmine tests?
How do I do that and where do I put it?**

Comment: Will importing in every test file `ConsoleTestModule` be applicable to you?

Comment: Yes, I think that would work - see solution from @AliF50. I'd still prefer a global `beforeEach()` if possible though, so I don't have to import this every time.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is a slight improvement, you can offset the mock provider into a module.

TestModuleForAll.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
const console = {
    error: () => {
    }
  };
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ ],
  providers:    [ {provide: CONSOLE, useValue: console} ],
})
export class TestModuleForAll{ }
```

Then put this module in your `imports` array of `TestBed.configureTestingModule`

```
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [TestModuleForAll],
    providers: []
  });
});
```

Comment: That's a good idea. I'm pretty new to Angular, and hadn't thought of writing a test module.

I'd still prefer to be able to do a global `beforeEach()` if this is possible though, so will wait to see if anyone has a solution to that before I mark this as the correct answer.